# php & mysql database pull error

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hello I have a website I am coding in php.  I have a database attached to it.  I am trying to get it to read the data into the pages from the database.  I have the database split into several tables.  I thought I had the code done properly but I keep on getting the error codes of the following:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 16

I been trying to research this for a while now and I just can not make heads or tails of this.  My code for the data pull and display is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT colConferenceName.tblConference, colSchoolName.tblSchool, colClass.tblSchool, colSurfaceName.tblSurface, colSurfaceCompany.tblSurface, colStadiumName.tblStadium, colAddress.tblStadium, colCity.tblStadium, colRegion.tblStadium, colCounty.tblStadium, colCapacity.tblStadium, colSurfaceYear.tblSurface FROM tblStadium, tblConference, tblSurface, tblSchool WHERE tblConference.colConferenceID = tblSchool.colConferenceID AND tblSurface.colSurfaceID = tblStadium.colSurfaceID AND tblStadium.colStadiumID = tblStadiumSchool.colStadiumID AND tblSchool.colSchoolID = tblStadiumSchool.colSchoolID AND colStadiumName LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY colSchoolName";
$schoolinfo = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_fetch_all($schoolinfo,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
while (!$schoolinfo->EOF){ //looping through the recordset (until End Of File) 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_all($schoolinfo,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<p>School Name: ' . $row['colSchoolName'] . '</br>Conference: ' . $row['colConferenceName'] . '</br>Class: ' . $row['colClass'] . '</br>Stadium Name: ' . $row['colStadiumName'] . '</br>Address: ' . $row['colAddress'] . '</br>City: ' . $row['colCity'] . '</br>County: ' . $row['colCounty'] . '</br>Region: ' . $row['colRegion'] . '</br>Capacity: ' . $row['colCapacity'] . '</br>Surface Type: ' . $row['colSurfaceName'] . '</br>Surface Company: ' . $row['colSurfaceCompany'] . '</br>Year Installed: ' . $row['colSurfaceYear'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
```

What ever help you can provide me would be awesome.  Thanks in advance.

As for the connection it is being done in a seperate connection file.  The way it pulls is $conn = require ('xxx_xxx.xxx');  I was principle asking about the output and how to fix the coding errors.  I xxx out the connection as I do not want people to have access to the file name.  I am also doing roughly 80 to 100 connections with this and as a result it makes more sense to use one file to do the connection than have to edit the connection part of each and every php file.  Plus I find it can have more security this way.

Comment: where are you setting your `$conn`

Comment: $conn = mysqli_conect().....

Comment: ****connect**** mysqli_connect double n

Comment: ah yes @CodeBird its connect not conect... my bad !!

Comment: also show the line where you are defining `$conn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

*Remember to set your db logins at the beginning of the script*

```
<?php

/* connect*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db_name");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* your sql query */
$query = "SELECT colConferenceName.tblConference, colSchoolName.tblSchool, ".
         "colClass.tblSchool, colSurfaceName.tblSurface, colSurfaceCompany.tblSurface, ".
         "colStadiumName.tblStadium, colAddress.tblStadium, colCity.tblStadium, ".
         "colRegion.tblStadium, colCounty.tblStadium, colCapacity.tblStadium, ".
         "colSurfaceYear.tblSurface FROM tblStadium, tblConference, tblSurface, tblSchool ".
         "WHERE tblConference.colConferenceID = tblSchool.colConferenceID AND ".
         "tblSurface.colSurfaceID = tblStadium.colSurfaceID AND ".
         "tblStadium.colStadiumID = tblStadiumSchool.colStadiumID AND ".
         "tblSchool.colSchoolID = tblStadiumSchool.colSchoolID AND ".
         "colStadiumName LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY colSchoolName";

/* query your db */
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        /* display row */
        echo '<p>School Name: ' . 
        $row['colSchoolName'] . '</br>Conference: ' . 
        $row['colConferenceName'] . '</br>Class: ' . 
        $row['colClass'] . '</br>Stadium Name: ' . 
        $row['colStadiumName'] . '</br>Address: ' . 
        $row['colAddress'] . '</br>City: ' . 
        $row['colCity'] . '</br>County: ' . 
        $row['colCounty'] . '</br>Region: ' . 
        $row['colRegion'] . '</br>Capacity: ' . 
        $row['colCapacity'] . '</br>Surface Type: ' . 
        $row['colSurfaceName'] . '</br>Surface Company: ' . 
        $row['colSurfaceCompany'] . '</br>Year Installed: ' . 
        $row['colSurfaceYear'] . '</p>';
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Well I tried it but it gave me the error, Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 29

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 29.  I should mention that the I have a seperate file for the connection as I am connecting to the database in about 80 to 100 seperate php pages.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a point in time where you connect to mysql. try [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('<your-host>','<your-username>','<your-password>','<your-databasename>').
```

Comment: Thanks but the connection is not the problem.  I did not want to show all of the background data for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the mysql server first:

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);

then you need to select the database you'll use:
$db = mysqli_db_select($database);

you also have to set the correct paramenters: $host, $username, $password and $database and your mysql server have to be configured first to accept the connection

well, why do you not try a php framework ?